# Switch Statement Not Switching

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, switch-statement

I am trying to create a state capital quiz game and am using a switch statement to insert the options and image based on a variable that is randomly select from an array.  All the states are held in an array and then the cities and image are held in an object.  The first state (Alabama) loads in okay, but when the variable is any other state I get a "cannot read property of '0' at undefined."  I though I had the switch statement set up correctly so I am a bit stuck here.  I would appreciate any help.  Thanks.

```js
<script>


        var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];

  var cities = {
        alabama: {
            image: 'state-images/alabama.jpg',
            options: ['Tuscaloosa', 'Montgomery', 'Birmingham', 'Huntsville']
        },

        alaska: {
            image: 'state-images/alaska.jpg',
            cities: ['Anchorage', 'Fairbanks', 'Juneau', 'Nome']
        },

        arizona: {
            image: 'state-images/arizona.jpg',
            cities: ['Tuscon', 'Scottsdale', 'Yuma', 'Phoenix']
        },

        arkansas: {
            image: 'state-images/arkansas.jpg',
            cities: ['Hot Springs', 'Pine Bluff', 'Little Rock', 'Fayetteville']
        },

        california: {
            image: 'state-images/california.jpg',
            cities: ['Los Angeles', 'San Diego', 'Stockton', 'Sacramento']
        },

        colorado: {
            image: 'state-images/colorado.jpg',
            cities: ['Denver', 'Fort Collins', 'Colorado Springs', 'Pueblo']
        },

        connecticut: {
            image: 'state-images/connecticut.jpg',
            cities: ['New Haven', 'Hartford', 'Stamford', 'Bridgeport']
        },

        delaware: {
            image: 'state-images/delaware.jpg',
            cities: ['Georgetown', 'Milford', 'Dover', 'Harrington']
        },

        florida: {
            image: 'state-images/florida.jpg',
            cities: ['Miami', 'Tallahassee', 'Jacksonville', 'St. Petersburg']
        },

        georgia: {
            image: 'state-images/georgia.jpg',
            cities: ['Atlanta', 'Macon', 'Albany', 'Augusta']
        },

        hawaii: {
            image: 'state-images/hawaii.jpg',
            cities: ['Hilo', 'Pearl City', 'Honolulu', 'Kailua']
        },

        idaho: {
            image: 'state-images/idaho.jpg',
            cities: ['Boise', 'Idaho Falls', 'Twin Falls', 'Pocatello']
        },

        illinois: {
            image: 'state-images/illinois.jpg',
            cities: ['Chicago', 'Peoria', 'Decatur', 'Springfield']
        },

        indiana: {
            image: 'state-images/indiana.jpg',
            cities: ['Bloomington', 'Fort Wayne', 'Indianapolis', 'South Bend']
        },

        iowa: {
            image: 'state-images/iowa.jpg',
            cities: ['Cedar Rapids', 'Des Moines', 'Council Bluffs', 'Waterloo']
        },

        kansas: {
            image: 'state-images/kansas.jpg',
            cities: ['Topeka', 'Kansas City', 'Wichita', 'Manhattan']
        },

        kentucky: {
            image: 'state-images/kentucky.jpg',
            cities: ['Frankfort', 'Lexington', 'Louisville', 'Bowling Green']
        },

        louisiana: {
            image: 'state-images/louisiana.jpg',
            cities: ['New Orleans', 'Lafayette', 'Baton Rouge', 'Shreveport']
        },

        maine: {
            image: 'state-images/maine.jpg',
            cities: ['Portland', 'Augusta', 'Millinocket', 'Portsmouth']
        },

        maryland: {
            image: 'state-images/maryland.jpg',
            cities: ['Baltimore', 'Annapolis', 'Salisbury', 'Hagerstown']
        },

        massachusetts: {
            image: 'state-images/massachusetts.jpg',
            cities: ['Providence', 'Lowell', 'Worcester', 'Boston']
        },

        michigan: {
            image: 'state-images/michigan.jpg',
            cities: ['Detriot', 'Grand Rapids', 'Lansing', 'Saginaw']
        },

        minnesota: {
            image: 'state-images/minnesota.jpg',
            cities: ['Minneapolis', 'St. Paul', 'Duluth', 'Moorhead']
        },

        mississippi: {
            image: 'state-images/mississippi.jpg',
            cities: ['Jackson', 'Tupelo', 'Hattiesburg', 'Columbus']
        },

        missouri: {
            image: 'state-images/missouri.jpg',
            cities: ['St. Louis', 'Jefferson City', 'Springfield', 'Independence']
        },

        montana: {
            image: 'state-images/montana.jpg',
            cities: ['Helena', 'Bozeman', 'Missoula', 'Billings']
        },

        nebraska: {
            image: 'state-images/nebraska.jpg',
            cities: ['Omaha', 'Bellevue', 'North Platte', 'Lincoln']
        },

        nevada: {
            image: 'state-images/nevada.jpg',
            cities: ['Reno', 'Carson City', 'Las Vegas', 'Henderson']
        },

        newHampshire: {
            image: 'state-images/new-hampshire.jpg',
            cities: ['Concord', 'Manchester', 'Haverhill', 'Littleton']
        },

        newJersey: {
            image: 'state-images/new-jersey.jpg',
            cities: ['Trenton', 'Elizabeth', 'Middleton', 'Atlantic City']
        },

        newMexico: {
            image: 'state-images/new-mexico.jpg',
            cities: ['Roswell', 'Santa Fe', 'Albuquerque', 'Carlsbad']
        },

        newYork: {
            image: 'state-images/new-york.jpg',
            cities: ['New York City', 'Syracuse', 'Albany', 'Rochester']
        },

        northCarolina: {
            image: 'state-images/north-carolina',
            cities: ['Charlotte', 'Raleigh', 'Fayetteville', 'Greensboro']
        },

        northDakota: {
            image: 'state-images/north-dakota',
            cities: ['Bismark', 'Fargo', 'Minot', 'Williston']
        },

        ohio: {
            image: 'state-images/ohio.jpg',
            cities: ['Cincinnati', 'Dayton', 'Cleveland', 'Columbus']
        },

        oklahoma: {
            image: 'state-images/oklahoma.jpg',
            cities: ['Tulsa', 'Oklahoma City', 'Norman', 'Broken Arrow']
        },

        oregon: {
            image: 'state-images/oregon.jpg',
            cities: ['Portland', 'Eugene', 'Medford', 'Salem']
        },

        pennsylvania: {
            image: 'state-images/pennsylvania.jpg',
            cities: ['Pittsburgh', 'Philadelphia', 'Harrisburg', 'Scranton']
        },

        rhodeIsland: {
            image: 'state-images/rhode-Island',
            cities: ['Providence', 'Warwick', 'Kingston', 'Woonsocket']
        },

        southCarolina: {
            image: 'state-images/south-carolina.jpg',
            cities: ['Spartanburg', 'Greenville', 'Columbia', 'Charleston']
        },

        southDakota: {
            image: 'state-images/south-dakota.jpg',
            cities: ['Rapid City', 'Sioux Falls', 'Sturgis', 'Pierre']
        },

        tennessee: {
            image: 'state-images/tennessee',
            cities: ['Nashville', 'Memphis', 'Knoxville', 'Chattanooga']
        },

        texas: {
            image: 'state-images/texas.jpg',
            cities: ['Houston', 'Dallas', 'San Antonio', 'Austin']
        },

        utah: {
            image: 'state-images/utah.jpg',
            cities: ['Salt Lake City', 'Provo', 'Ogden', 'St. George']
        },

        vermont: {
            image: 'state-images/vermont.jpg',
            cities: ['Burlington', 'Montpelier', 'Rutland', 'Newport']
        },

        virginia: {
            image: 'state-images/virginia.jpg',
            cities: ['Lynchburg', 'Roanoke', 'Richmond', 'Norfolk']
        },

        washington: {
            image: 'state-images/washington.jpg',
            cities: ['Seattle', 'Tacoma', 'Spokane', 'Olympia']
        },

        westVirginia: {
            image: 'state-images/west-virginia',
            cities: ['Parkersburg', 'Morgantown', 'Charleston', 'Bluefield']
        },

        wisconsin: {
            image: 'state-images/wisconsin.jpg',
            cities: ['Milwaukee', 'Madison', 'Green Bay', 'Superior']
        },

        wyoming: {
            image: 'state-images/wyoming.jpg',
            cities: ['Cheyenne', 'Casper', 'Gillette', 'Jackson']
        }
    }
    
        var currentState = states[Math.floor(Math.random() * states.length)];

        function getState() {

        document.getElementById('activeState').innerHTML = currentState;

        }

        getState();

        console.log(currentState);



        



        switch(currentState) {
            case 'Alabama':
                document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = cities.alabama.options[0];
                document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = cities.alabama.options[1];
                document.getElementById('choice3').innerHTML = cities.alabama.options[2];
                document.getElementById('choice4').innerHTML = cities.alabama.options[3];
                document.getElementById('stateImage').src='state-images/alabama.jpg';
                break;
            
            case 'Alaska':
                document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = cities.alaska.options[0];
                document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = cities.alaska.options[1];
                document.getElementById('choice3').innerHTML = cities.alaska.options[2];
                document.getElementById('choice4').innerHTML = cities.alaska.options[3];
                document.getElementById('stateImage').src='state-images/alaska.jpg';
                break;

            case 'Arizona':
                document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = cities.arizona.options[0];
                document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = cities.arizona.options[1];
                document.getElementById('choice3').innerHTML = cities.arizona.options[2];
                document.getElementById('choice4').innerHTML = cities.arizona.options[3];
                document.getElementById('stateImage').src='state-images/arizona.jpg';
                break;

            case 'Arkansas':
                document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = cities.arkansas.options[0];
                document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = cities.arkansas.options[1];
                document.getElementById('choice3').innerHTML = cities.arkansas.options[2];
                document.getElementById('choice4').innerHTML = cities.arkansas.options[3];
                document.getElementById('stateImage').src='state-images/arkansas.jpg';
                break; 

            case 'California':
                document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = cities.california.options[0];
                document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = cities.california.options[1];
                document.getElementById('choice3').innerHTML = cities.california.options[2];
                document.getElementById('choice4').innerHTML = cities.california.options[3];
                document.getElementById('stateImage').src='state-images/california.jpg';
                break;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
    <title>State Capital Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="question">
            <p>What is the Capital of</p>
            <p id='activeState'></p>
        </div>
        <div class="state-image">
            <img id='stateImage' src="State-images/alabama.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="options">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button id="choice1"></button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button id="choice2"></button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button id="choice3"></button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button id="choice4"></button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Answer (score 0):

For alabama you have `options` key existing in your object meanwhile for rest of the states you have `cities` key and that's why when you're trying to access `options` in switch case for any state except alabama, `options` is coming as `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Lakshya is correct you need to have the attributes the same for each object.
Also I would suggest turning your object identifiers for each state into strings and that way you will be able to reference the state without having to write a case for each state.

```
  var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'];

  var cities = {
        'Alabama': {
            image: 'state-images/alabama.jpg',
            options: ['Tuscaloosa', 'Montgomery', 'Birmingham', 'Huntsville']
        },

        'Alaska': {
            image: 'state-images/alaska.jpg',
            options: ['Anchorage', 'Fairbanks', 'Juneau', 'Nome']
        },

        'Arizona': {
            image: 'state-images/arizona.jpg',
            options: ['Tuscon', 'Scottsdale', 'Yuma', 'Phoenix']
        }


    }

        var currentState = states[0];

        function getState() {

        document.getElementById('activeState').innerHTML = currentState;

        }

        getState();

        console.log(currentState);




                document.getElementById('choice1').innerHTML = cities[currentState].options[0];
                document.getElementById('choice2').innerHTML = cities[currentState].options[1];
                document.getElementById('choice3').innerHTML = cities[currentState].options[2];
                document.getElementById('choice4').innerHTML = cities[currentState].options[3];
                document.getElementById('stateImage').src='state-images/' + currentState.toLowerCase() + '.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little refactor for you and placed a default case in your switch and case statement

```js
const states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];


const cities = {
  alabama: {
    image: "state-images/alabama.jpg",
    options: ["Tuscaloosa", "Montgomery", "Birmingham", "Huntsville"],
  },

  alaska: {
    image: "state-images/alaska.jpg",
    cities: ["Anchorage", "Fairbanks", "Juneau", "Nome"],
  },

  arizona: {
    image: "state-images/arizona.jpg",
    cities: ["Tuscon", "Scottsdale", "Yuma", "Phoenix"],
  },

  arkansas: {
    image: "state-images/arkansas.jpg",
    cities: ["Hot Springs", "Pine Bluff", "Little Rock", "Fayetteville"],
  },

  california: {
    image: "state-images/california.jpg",
    cities: ["Los Angeles", "San Diego", "Stockton", "Sacramento"],
  },

  colorado: {
    image: "state-images/colorado.jpg",
    cities: ["Denver", "Fort Collins", "Colorado Springs", "Pueblo"],
  },

  connecticut: {
    image: "state-images/connecticut.jpg",
    cities: ["New Haven", "Hartford", "Stamford", "Bridgeport"],
  },

  delaware: {
    image: "state-images/delaware.jpg",
    cities: ["Georgetown", "Milford", "Dover", "Harrington"],
  },

  florida: {
    image: "state-images/florida.jpg",
    cities: ["Miami", "Tallahassee", "Jacksonville", "St. Petersburg"],
  },

  georgia: {
    image: "state-images/georgia.jpg",
    cities: ["Atlanta", "Macon", "Albany", "Augusta"],
  },

  hawaii: {
    image: "state-images/hawaii.jpg",
    cities: ["Hilo", "Pearl City", "Honolulu", "Kailua"],
  },

  idaho: {
    image: "state-images/idaho.jpg",
    cities: ["Boise", "Idaho Falls", "Twin Falls", "Pocatello"],
  },

  illinois: {
    image: "state-images/illinois.jpg",
    cities: ["Chicago", "Peoria", "Decatur", "Springfield"],
  },

  indiana: {
    image: "state-images/indiana.jpg",
    cities: ["Bloomington", "Fort Wayne", "Indianapolis", "South Bend"],
  },

  iowa: {
    image: "state-images/iowa.jpg",
    cities: ["Cedar Rapids", "Des Moines", "Council Bluffs", "Waterloo"],
  },

  kansas: {
    image: "state-images/kansas.jpg",
    cities: ["Topeka", "Kansas City", "Wichita", "Manhattan"],
  },

  kentucky: {
    image: "state-images/kentucky.jpg",
    cities: ["Frankfort", "Lexington", "Louisville", "Bowling Green"],
  },

  louisiana: {
    image: "state-images/louisiana.jpg",
    cities: ["New Orleans", "Lafayette", "Baton Rouge", "Shreveport"],
  },

  maine: {
    image: "state-images/maine.jpg",
    cities: ["Portland", "Augusta", "Millinocket", "Portsmouth"],
  },

  maryland: {
    image: "state-images/maryland.jpg",
    cities: ["Baltimore", "Annapolis", "Salisbury", "Hagerstown"],
  },

  massachusetts: {
    image: "state-images/massachusetts.jpg",
    cities: ["Providence", "Lowell", "Worcester", "Boston"],
  },

  michigan: {
    image: "state-images/michigan.jpg",
    cities: ["Detriot", "Grand Rapids", "Lansing", "Saginaw"],
  },

  minnesota: {
    image: "state-images/minnesota.jpg",
    cities: ["Minneapolis", "St. Paul", "Duluth", "Moorhead"],
  },

  mississippi: {
    image: "state-images/mississippi.jpg",
    cities: ["Jackson", "Tupelo", "Hattiesburg", "Columbus"],
  },

  missouri: {
    image: "state-images/missouri.jpg",
    cities: ["St. Louis", "Jefferson City", "Springfield", "Independence"],
  },

  montana: {
    image: "state-images/montana.jpg",
    cities: ["Helena", "Bozeman", "Missoula", "Billings"],
  },

  nebraska: {
    image: "state-images/nebraska.jpg",
    cities: ["Omaha", "Bellevue", "North Platte", "Lincoln"],
  },

  nevada: {
    image: "state-images/nevada.jpg",
    cities: ["Reno", "Carson City", "Las Vegas", "Henderson"],
  },

  newHampshire: {
    image: "state-images/new-hampshire.jpg",
    cities: ["Concord", "Manchester", "Haverhill", "Littleton"],
  },

  newJersey: {
    image: "state-images/new-jersey.jpg",
    cities: ["Trenton", "Elizabeth", "Middleton", "Atlantic City"],
  },

  newMexico: {
    image: "state-images/new-mexico.jpg",
    cities: ["Roswell", "Santa Fe", "Albuquerque", "Carlsbad"],
  },

  newYork: {
    image: "state-images/new-york.jpg",
    cities: ["New York City", "Syracuse", "Albany", "Rochester"],
  },

  northCarolina: {
    image: "state-images/north-carolina",
    cities: ["Charlotte", "Raleigh", "Fayetteville", "Greensboro"],
  },

  northDakota: {
    image: "state-images/north-dakota",
    cities: ["Bismark", "Fargo", "Minot", "Williston"],
  },

  ohio: {
    image: "state-images/ohio.jpg",
    cities: ["Cincinnati", "Dayton", "Cleveland", "Columbus"],
  },

  oklahoma: {
    image: "state-images/oklahoma.jpg",
    cities: ["Tulsa", "Oklahoma City", "Norman", "Broken Arrow"],
  },

  oregon: {
    image: "state-images/oregon.jpg",
    cities: ["Portland", "Eugene", "Medford", "Salem"],
  },

  pennsylvania: {
    image: "state-images/pennsylvania.jpg",
    cities: ["Pittsburgh", "Philadelphia", "Harrisburg", "Scranton"],
  },

  rhodeIsland: {
    image: "state-images/rhode-Island",
    cities: ["Providence", "Warwick", "Kingston", "Woonsocket"],
  },

  southCarolina: {
    image: "state-images/south-carolina.jpg",
    cities: ["Spartanburg", "Greenville", "Columbia", "Charleston"],
  },

  southDakota: {
    image: "state-images/south-dakota.jpg",
    cities: ["Rapid City", "Sioux Falls", "Sturgis", "Pierre"],
  },

  tennessee: {
    image: "state-images/tennessee",
    cities: ["Nashville", "Memphis", "Knoxville", "Chattanooga"],
  },

  texas: {
    image: "state-images/texas.jpg",
    cities: ["Houston", "Dallas", "San Antonio", "Austin"],
  },

  utah: {
    image: "state-images/utah.jpg",
    cities: ["Salt Lake City", "Provo", "Ogden", "St. George"],
  },

  vermont: {
    image: "state-images/vermont.jpg",
    cities: ["Burlington", "Montpelier", "Rutland", "Newport"],
  },

  virginia: {
    image: "state-images/virginia.jpg",
    cities: ["Lynchburg", "Roanoke", "Richmond", "Norfolk"],
  },

  washington: {
    image: "state-images/washington.jpg",
    cities: ["Seattle", "Tacoma", "Spokane", "Olympia"],
  },

  westVirginia: {
    image: "state-images/west-virginia",
    cities: ["Parkersburg", "Morgantown", "Charleston", "Bluefield"],
  },

  wisconsin: {
    image: "state-images/wisconsin.jpg",
    cities: ["Milwaukee", "Madison", "Green Bay", "Superior"],
  },

  wyoming: {
    image: "state-images/wyoming.jpg",
    cities: ["Cheyenne", "Casper", "Gillette", "Jackson"],
  },
};

const currentState = states[Math.floor(Math.random() * states.length)];

function getState() {
  document.getElementById("activeState").innerHTML = currentState;
}

getState();

const setInnerHtml = city => {
  document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = cities[city].options[0];
  document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = cities[city].options[1];
  document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML = cities[bity].options[2];
  document.getElementById("choice4").innerHTML = cities[city].options[3];
  document.getElementById("stateImage").src = "state-images/alabama.jpg";
};

const setImage = city => { 
  document.getElementById("stateImage").src = `state-images/${city}.jpg`;
};

switch (currentState) {
  case "Alabama":
    setInnerHtml("alabama")
    setImage("alabama")
    break;

  case "Alaska":
    setInnerHtml("alaska")
    setImage("alaska")
    break;

  case "Arizona":
    setInnerHtml("arizona")
    setImage("arizona")
    break;

  case "Arkansas":
    setInnerHtml("arkansas")
    setImage("arkansas")
    break;

  case "California":
    setInnerHtml("california")
    setImage("california")
    break;
  default:
    console.log(`Current state is: ${currentState} and does not match any case!`);
}
```